# Borel sigma algebra and an extra point

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I have a question about Borel sigma algebra on a topological space.

Let $E$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $\mathcal{B}(E)$ denotes its Borel sigma algebra. We adjoin an extra point $\Delta$ to $E$ as an isolated point to obtain a Hausdorff topological space $E_{\Delta}:=E\cup \{\Delta\}$. 
I am considering about sigma algebra on $E_{\Delta}$. For example $\mathcal{B}(E)\cup\{ {{B\cup\{\Delta}\}}|B \in \mathcal{B}(E)\}$ is sigma algebra on $E_{\Delta}$. 
Conversely, what is the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $E_{\Delta}$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{T})=\mathcal{B}(E)\cup\{ {{B\cup\{\Delta}\}}|B \in \mathcal{B}(E)\}$?

Comment: Did you try the collection of subsets $O\cup G$ with $O$ in the topology of $E$ and $G=\varnothing$ or $G=\{\Delta\}$?

Comment: Well... to begin with, T' is "larger" than T so B=sigma(T) should be included in T', no?

Comment: ((Comment by the OP now deleted.))

Comment: Sorry I have deleted  by mistake.

Comment: I agree with you.